# Installing Second Lumen Project,

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, lumen

I tried to install Lumen on my mac for the first time. Please note that I have another Laravel project that is currently working on `192.168.10.10`. My problem is that whatever I do, it's directing to my other previous Laravel project, even though I change `etc/hosts` files.

I did:

- `cd Code`, `mkdir Lumen`, `cd Code/Lumen` and then `cd` to go back to main root.
- `composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0"`:
- Here I received greens and a yellow `Changed current directory to /Users/senty/.composer`.
- `cd Code/Lumen`
- `lumen new Lumen` : `Application ready! Build something amazing.`

Then,

- in Lumen directory:`composer require laravel/homestead`
- also in Lument dir: `php vendor/bin/homestead make` : 
  Homestead Installed!

Everything looks ok until here. Note that I already have a Laravel project working on `192.168.10.10`.

---

Now I got to `cd Code/Lumen`, opened `Homestead.yaml` and first, I changed `sites: - map:` from `localhost.app` to `lumen.app`

Then, I tried changing `192.168.10.10` at the top to `192.168.20.20` (as it's same for the other project).

Also in my `etc/hosts` file, I tried

`192.168.10.10 laravel.app` - this was working and still works
`192.168.10.10 lumen.app` - this one directing to laravel.app directory.

When I also change it to `192.168.20.20 lumen.app`, I get error:

> `This webpage is not available ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

When I remove `192.168.10.10 laravel.app` and just leave `192.168.10.10 lumen.app`, I receive:

> `No input file specified.

---

What am I doing wrong or missing? I want to be able to access both projects through different urls as `lumen.app` & `laravel.app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `vagrant provision`, but first make sure you have this:

**Homestead.yaml**

In `sites`, map both `laravel.app` and `lumen.app` to the correct folder.

**Hosts file**

```
192.168.10.10        laravel.app
192.168.10.10        lumen.app
```

Comment: `vagrant reload --provision` was the key